# Google Calendar Bug (/basic works but /full doesn't) since this morning

Tags: api, google-calendar-api

I'm creating some software for a client and am integrating Google Calendar.

The following URL (the 'full' one) worked yesterday but has suddenly stopped working this morning.

The settings are set to public and everything as it should but it now just responds with a 403.

The funny thing (and bug) is this URL works:

https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/artisan.codesmith%40gmail.com/public/basic

But this doesn't (the only difference is the basic/full part):

https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/artisan.codesmith%40gmail.com/public/full

--

The problem is I need to use the /full URL in order to get the functionality required for this calendar.

Thanks for any help you can all provide!! :)

Comment: I can't add more than 2 links so I'll add this here, I think it's a Google error as the URL on this page also shows the 403:

https://developers.google.com/gdata/samples/cal_sample

--

Replace the "full" part of the URL on that page with "basic" and it will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Calendar API v2 has been deprecated and was shut down this morning: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/reference

Comment: Noooooo, thanks - I'll have to rewrite the jQuery plugin I'm using. D:

Comment: Correct. The basic feeds still work for now for XML feedreaders, but the full feeds are considered part of the V2 API that was shut down. The V3 equivalent is https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/artisan.codesmith%40gmail.com/events?key={YOUR_API_KEY}